# distinct on specific column values postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with three columns

```
|   name             |    date    | total |
--------------------------------------------
| name.first_name    | 2019-12-10 |   1   |
| name.last_name     | 2019-12-10 |   1   |
| name.middle_name   | 2019-12-10 |   1   |
| name.full_name     | 2019-12-10 |   1   |
| dob                | 2019-12-10 |   1   |
| expiry_date        | 2019-12-10 |   1   |
```

I need the following result

```
|   name             |    date    | total |
--------------------------------------------
| name.first_name    | 2019-12-10 |   1   |
| dob                | 2019-12-10 |   1   |
| expiry_date        | 2019-12-10 |   1   |
```

meaning i want the 'name.' value of the column to be distinct basically take as one or in other words merge to one where as the rest remain the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT split_part(Name, '.', 1),dateField,total FROM New_NAMES;
```

[online sample](https://rextester.com/COJAV84380)